# problema al obtener el numero del dia de la semana en sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, base-de-datos

Tengo la siguiente consulta

```
SELECT DATEPART(WEEKDAY,'2018-01-18')
```

lo que quiero es ejemplo que si ese dia es jueves ejemplo me devuelva un 3 porque en la tabla que tengo los dias empiezan desde el 0 hasta el 6 el campo es de tipo int y se llama `DAYID`, por cuando utilizo la consulta antes mencionada me devulve el numero 5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si lo que quieres es una función (no sé si recomendarte) que retorne el día de la semana, sin considerar la respuesta anterior (la cuál es válida). Tendrías que hacer, por ejemplo:

```
CREATE FUNCTION UDF_DIASEMANA(
    @FECHA DATETIME
)    
RETURNS INT
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @DIA INT = DATEPART(WEEKDAY, @FECHA)

    RETURN @DIA + CASE WHEN @DIA >= 2 THEN -2 ELSE 5 END
END
GO

SELECT 
    DBO.UDF_DIASEMANA('20180115'),
    DBO.UDF_DIASEMANA('20180116'),
    DBO.UDF_DIASEMANA('20180117'),
    DBO.UDF_DIASEMANA('20180118'),
    DBO.UDF_DIASEMANA('20180119'),
    DBO.UDF_DIASEMANA('20180120'),
    DBO.UDF_DIASEMANA('20180121'),
    DBO.UDF_DIASEMANA('20180122')
```

Obtendrás:

> ```
> +---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
> | 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 0 |
> +---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
> ```

[**DEMO**](http://rextester.com/HMLUW3719)

Answer (score 1):

Sql server enumera los días de la semana del 1 al 7 empezando por el domingo como día 1, sábado día 7, para lograr lo que necesitas usa:

```
--Indicamos al motor que el lunes lo considere como el primer dia de la semana
SET DATEFIRST 1
--Al enumerar los dias de la semana del 1 al 7 necesitamos
--restar 1 a la enumeración para que concuerde con la tabla que tienes
SELECT (DATEPART(WEEKDAY,'2018-01-18') - 1)  -- resultado 3
SELECT (DATEPART(WEEKDAY,'2018-01-15') - 1)  -- resultado 0
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/9eecb7db59d16c80417c72d1e1f4fbf1/18721/0)

Comment: Te Endiendo y en verdad lo se que los enumera asi, y te doy toda la razon lo que pasa es que la aplicacion le indicaron que 0 seria el primer dia de la sema y si le indico que que sea 0 me da un error @Lamak,@Jesus Rodriguez

Comment: En realidad no puede usar `SET DATEFIRST 2` solamente pues en ese caso `SELECT DATEPART(WEEKDAY,'2018-01-15')` da como resultado 7 y no 0 como lo desea, Saludos

Comment: Rodriguez Exacto, por eso digo que el datefirst no me funcionaria porque lo que necesito evaluar es si es de 0 a 6 porque asi es que lo tengo en las tablas

Comment: @Frankenstainero podrias explicar mejor tu pregunta porfavor para ayudarete, debido a que si no buscas que `DATEPART` retorne de 0 a 6 siendo 0 el lunes pude haber comprendido mal lo que buscas

Comment: rodriguez Busco una funcion que me pueda realizar eso

Comment: @Frankenstainero entonces el codigo que te presento lo realiza, revisa el enlace de fiddle que te deje donde puedes ver la enumeracion completa de la semana, Saludos

Comment: Rodriguez lo intente pero eso no me funciono la respuesta que me dejaste